# Horizontal scrolling site with vertical scrolling elements

Tags: html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to create a site very much like in this picture:

[Layout Image on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qe9qpv6g3rte7yy/scrollingsample.jpg)

**The Problem:**

- I need the site to scroll horizontally, as suggested in the image.
- I also need the vertically scrolling elements to scroll, but inside the element itself, not the entire site. When I scroll up/down in the first frame of the site, it scrolls down to a blank area because the second frame is so tall and forces the entire site to be as tall as the tallest element.

**HTML structure:**

```
div #horizontal-container
    div #horizontal-wrapper
        div #section-1 .section
        div #section-2 .section
        div #section-3 .section
        so on...
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#horizontal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#horizontal-wrapper {
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
}

.section {
    width: 25%; /* A quarter of its parent with 400%, to be 100% of the window. */
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Hopefully I made it clear here. What am I missing to get this working? Should I maybe incorporate a little JavaScript to toggle the `overflow` property of the container when I hit certain horizontal scroll points? That sounds messy. :/

Comment: I bet you need some jquery module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

height=100% will not introduce scroll to sections

You have to assign different heights to sections based on there content.

Check by javascript If height of section is more than window height then assign window height to the section height.

Comment: I'm trying to do this without JavaScript, but I managed to find a solution that works pretty well. Check the answer below. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: **The Solution:**

http://jsfiddle.net/RCJuX/

I needed to set a fixed height of some kind from the top container element, and then pass it down the tree using `height: 100%` in order to match it. So as long as there is a **fixed** height of some kind, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to generate fixed width content blocks with horizontal scroller. You can see the parent post [here](http://www.htmlexplorer.com/2014/02/horizontal-scrolling-webpage-content.html)

```
<html>
<title>HTMLExplorer Demo: Horizontal Scrolling Content</title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#outer_wrapper {  
    overflow: scroll;  
    width:100%;
}
#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper {
    width:6000px; /* If you have more elements, increase the width accordingly */
}
#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper div.box { /* Define the properties of inner block */
    width: 250px;
    height:300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    border:1px grey solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="outer_wrapper">
    <div id="inner_wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <!-- more boxes here -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```